# We can forecast the direction of (constant maturity) implied vol of various indices well. Is that useful?

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, option-strategies

We've been financial building ML models for years, and have multiple portfolios live - but we're new to the volatility space, none of us are options traders.

1. How could we effectively use implied vol forecasts to trade with minimal friction, aside from the VIX futures? (we can predict it well for almost all assets/asset classes)
2. Would a model be useful for an options trading firm? **How** would they potentially use it?
3. Are there models in widespread use that options trading firms already use to the direction of implied vol?
4. Is it more actionable to predict implied vol or realized vol, in general?
5. Is a directional forecast or an point prediction more useful, for predicting volatility?

Thanks!